# Why am I getting the wrong output - If & Else statements

Tags: c++, if-statement

The desription of what I am supposed to do is listed below. THe program runs but I can't get the right numbers to come out in the output.  I think the logic is right but it is not working.

We get the # of cookies, the boxes will = # of cookies divided by 24 and if there are extra cookies > than 0 we add one box.

We take the # of boxes, extra boxes is > 0 we add one shipping container .

We then have the total number of shipping containers and boxes.

I don't know why it is not working and have been stuck on this problem for the past 3 hours and finally given up and asked for help.

A box of cookies can hold 24 cookies, and a container can hold 75 boxes of
cookies. Write a program that prompts the user to enter the total number of
cookies, the number of cookies in a box, and the number of cookie boxes in a
container. The program then outputs the number of boxes and the number of
containers to ship the cookies. Note that each box must contain the specified
number of cookies, and each container must contain the specified number of
boxes. If the last box of cookies contains less than the number of specified
cookies, you can discard it and output the number of leftover cookies. Similarly,
if the last container contains less than the number of specified boxes, you can
 discard it and output the number of leftover boxes. Because this is a chapter
  on Selectional Control Structure, if there are no cookies or no boxes
   remaining then the remaining cookies or remaining boxes must not be output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
// Declare variables
    int cookies, extraCookies;
    int boxes,totalBoxes;
    int leftOverBoxes;
    int containers;
    boxes = (cookies/24);

    extraCookies = cookies%24;
    containers = boxes/75;
    leftOverBoxes = boxes%75;


//  Ask for the user input ( doesnt make sense because we are given the capacities)
    cout << " How many cookies do you have ?"<< endl;
    cin >> cookies;
    cout << " You have this many cookies: " << cookies << endl;

    cout << " How many cookies can you fit in one box ?" << endl;
    cin >> cookies;

    cout << " How many cookie boxes can you fit into a container ?" << endl;
    cin >> boxes;

    // Computer number of boxes needed
    if(extraCookies > 0)
      totalBoxes = (boxes + 1);
    cout <<" We need this many boxes:" << totalBoxes << endl;

    if(leftOverBoxes > 0)
      containers = ( containers + 1);
    cout << "We need this many containers: " << containers << endl;


    return 0;



    }
```

Comment: The code runs but it does not actually give me the correct numbers and I have been stuck for the past 3 hours trying to figure this out.  Can someone please help me ?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend taking the [tour] and learning [ask] before continuing.

Comment: Simply providing the question you've been asked and your solution so far is not sufficient for a Stack Overflow question. Please explain what your example is suppose to do, what it's actually doing, what you've tried and the results of those efforts.

Comment: Ok I have added what is going on

Comment: You use `cookie`'s value prior to its initialization

Comment: Your toolchain can help you find such mistakes. If it's gcc, try `-Wall`

Comment: I have no idea what toolchain is - wall ???? 

I have been doing coding for about 4 weeks total and have only read 4 chapters.....

I just tried moving the values below the input and it is still not working. I honestly have no idea what anyone is talking about. Straight newbie status here....

Comment: @JoeBrown The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ 
I am using Atom on a macbook and it does not give me any runtime compile errors. I have installed visual studio code which supports C++ on macbook, however I can't get the programs to run/build there. I have spent countless hours online looking for answers on how to get programs to run from VSCode, because that actually has debugger errors ect. 


If you know how to get VSCode to run, then please enlighten me. Apparently my questions sucks and have now been blocked from asking anymore questions.  My teacher just assumes everyone has windows and will not help me.

Comment: @JoeBrown Do you actually know what a debugger is? It's is used to step through your code line by line and inspect how variables are changing. Also for example you are using uninitialized variables e.g. here: `extraCookies = cookies%24;`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is there a way we cant chat, I'd like to avoid pissing other people off with my questions. Getting blocked in this supposedly friendly community isn't enjoyable when I am just trying to learn this stuff. 

I don't have a debugger on atom like I said. Visual Studio Code has one but it will not build/run/compile or whatever you would like to call it. 

I have been doing this for 4 weeks now with no debugging and it has been a pain.

Comment: @JoeBrown https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler

Comment: @JoeBrown Also what's so hard to get about you should move your calculations after the input of these variables you use? You should note that _this friendly community_ isn't your personal help desk, but is looking for hight quality questions and answers that are useful for future research.

Comment: Dude I did do that and it still isn't working. I get that this isn't a personal help desk, I have avoided coming here to ask questions until today. Online resources have been my friend, but when you get stuck what else do you do ? It's an online class and I have no clue what I am doing. Better to ask and get shamed than keep running in circles like I have been for the last 4 hours....@

Answer (score 0):

C++ is read top to bottom. Allow me to add comments to your code, explaining what's going on:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std; // Bad practice, by the way

int main()

{
// Declare variables
    int cookies, extraCookies; // cookies = 0, extraCookies = 0
    int boxes,totalBoxes; // boxes = 0, totalBoxes = 0
    int leftOverBoxes; // leftOverBoxes = 0
    int containers; // containers = 0
    boxes = (cookies/24); // boxes = 0/24 = 0, this line does nothing

    extraCookies = cookies%24; // extraCookies = 0%24 = 0, this line does nothing
    containers = boxes/75; // containers = 0/75 = 0, this line does nothing
    leftOverBoxes = boxes%75; // leftOverBoxes = 0%75 = 0, this line does nothing


//  Ask for the user input ( doesnt make sense because we are given the capacities)
    cout << " How many cookies do you have ?"<< endl;
    cin >> cookies;
    cout << " You have this many cookies: " << cookies << endl;

    cout << " How many cookies can you fit in one box ?" << endl;
    cin >> cookies; // You throw away how many cookies the user has, and rewrite it with how many cookies fit in one box

    cout << " How many cookie boxes can you fit into a container ?" << endl;
    cin >> boxes;

    // Computer number of boxes needed
    if(extraCookies > 0) // 0 > 0 == false
      totalBoxes = (boxes + 1);
    cout <<" We need this many boxes:" << totalBoxes << endl;

    if(leftOverBoxes > 0) // 0 > 0 == false
      containers = ( containers + 1);
    cout << "We need this many containers: " << containers << endl;


    return 0;



    }
```

You're calculating `boxes`, `extraCookies`, `containers`, and `leftOverBoxes` before taking the input from the user. They're all initialized to 0.

You should calculate them after taking the input from the user.

Think of code as a series of instructions. You can't figure out how many boxes you need if you don't have the ammount of cookies yet.

Comment: I am newbie, so that means I need to move those calculations below the if statements ?

Comment: Above the if statements, below the input taking.

Comment: So why is the line cookies/24 do nothing  ? I thought I could use operators on words ? 

From what I can tell pretty much most of my code is doing nothing ??? I have read the entire chapter related to this mini project and I guess I am completely lost.  I can;t think of any other way to do this ?

Comment: I moved them to the correct spot and I keep getting 0 when I run the program

Comment: When I say it does nothing, I mean it sets 0 to 0. It's crucial to the logic, but only if placed in the right place.

Comment: For example if we have 36 cookies inputed by the user, then we should have 2 boxes and 1 shipping container. 

Or if we had 1801 cookies, we should have 76 boxes, 2 shipping containers, but for some reason the user input is not saving and being used when calculating the required items....this does not make sense as to why they are not being used and then outputted correctly.

Comment: I guess I just don't know enough about code to understand why it is being set to 0.  Do I need to set my variables to strings 

string cookies = 0 
string boxes = 0 
ect 

Will that then allow me to get the user inputed #s in its place to actually run ?

Comment: There's a line where you throw away the cookies. Pay attention. Don't freak out, there is no need for string juggling.

Comment: Automatic variables are not zero-initialized.

Comment: @molbdnilo they are if your compiler is nice to you. Non-standard though. Also, a bit over the OPs head don't you think?

Comment: I added another variable totalCookies and changed the input on - How many cookies do you have 

/  Ask for the user input ( doesnt make sense because we are given the capacities)
    cout << " How many cookies do you have ?"<< endl;
    cin >> totalCookies;
    cout << " You have this many cookies: " << totalCookies << endl;

    cout << " How many cookies can you fit in one box ?" << endl;
    cin >> cookies; // You throw away how many cookies the user has, and rewrite it with how many cookies fit in one box

 Still not working

Comment: Well sorry for the confusion guys, I suck at this and am just trying to learn. It's been going well until this. I have hit a brick wall.

Comment: Print the variables, see what's inside. Move those prints around and see how the values change based on what was done previously. You're learning debugging, which is the other 60% of coding

Comment: Do you have an example you can provide or online resource I should go read ? I keep changing things around and am lost. 

I get that I need to get the # of cookies first, which I thought that is precisely what I was doing when I asked the user to input that. 

From there I thought I could use an if statement for leftovercookies, bc the equation takes total cookies / 24 giving us leftovercookies using the % operator. 

From there we know how many boxes we need because cookies / 24 = boxes
 IF the remainder is >0 then we know we need to add one box ....but none of this code is working...

Comment: Is it because the ifs are happening before the calculations? Or because the calculations happening before taking the input?

Comment: Well the calculation is now happening after I take the input. The if statements follow the calculations which then include the output. 

I don't understand why boxes = (cookies/24)    // is actually 0/24 because Say we input 26, then it should be 1 box.   

For extraCookies = cookies%24 // The input is 26 so the remainder is 2 

which then for the if statement extracookies is > 0 because extracookies now = 2

Which then the totalboxes has an equation for boxes we just calculated and add 1 to it....

That is how i am thinking about it, but as to why is it not working. I am clueless

Comment: @IvanRubinson 

Is there syntax that I can use to get results on the following:
So set it that 1 container holds 75 boxes and want to calculate how many containers, what syntax would I use ? 
Example:

if boxes <= 75 = 1 container if boxes <= 150 && >75 =2 container if boxes <=225 && > 150 =3 containers...

This is what I am trying to achieve, however how can I make it continuous ? What if the user has say 10,000 boxes ? I don't want to have to continuously write if statements over and over, I feel like there has to be a method for this ?

Comment: You divide. Just like you did.